# Match all occurrences from the same dictionary in one line in UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I have type Dog, which has features `size`, `color` and `other`

Size wordlist: `big, medium, small`

Other wordlist: `old, fat, happy, lazy`

Color wordlist does not affect anything in this case, so I won't list it.

And my code (just for the main file):

```
PACKAGE dog;

SCRIPT dog.Color;
SCRIPT dog.Size;
SCRIPT dog.Other;

TYPESYSTEM dogTypeSystemDescriptor;

ENGINE utils.PlainTextAnnotator;
TYPESYSTEM utils.PlainTextTypeSystem;

Document{-> CALL(Color)};
Document{-> CALL(Size)};
Document{-> CALL(Other)};

Document{-> EXEC(PlainTextAnnotator, {Line})};

Line{-> CREATE(Dog, "color" = Color, "size" = Size, "other" = Other)};

DECLARE Max, Milo;

Dog{Dog.color.ct == "black", 
    Dog.size.ct == "big" -> Max};

Dog{Dog.color.ct == "white", 
    Dog.other.ct == "fat" -> Milo};
```

As you can see on the picture, **annotation "Milo" is never created** (because it relies on the value "fat" of the feature "other" which is in the same dictionary with the "happy", but in the input word "happy" goes before "fat"). If we put "fat" before "happy" in the input - everything works as expected.

So, **the question is** how can I have annotations created for the each single feature from the same dictionary found in the same input?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafael has it right, but I would recommend an FSArray instead of the list. Here's an example tested with Ruta 2.6.1. Mind the "s" in feature "others" and its type FSArray.

```
ENGINE utils.PlainTextAnnotator;
TYPESYSTEM utils.PlainTextTypeSystem;

// mock dictionary lookup and scripts
DECLARE Color, Size, Other;
"black|white" -> Color;
"big|small" -> Size;
"lazy|happy|fat" -> Other;

DECLARE Dog (Color color, Size size, FSArray others);

Document{-> EXEC(PlainTextAnnotator, {Line})};

Line{-> CREATE(Dog, "color" = Color, "size" = Size, "others" = Other)};

DECLARE Max, Milo;

Dog{Dog.color.ct == "black", 
    Dog.size.ct == "big" -> Max};

Dog{Dog.color.ct == "white", 
    Dog.others.ct == "fat" -> Milo};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Answer (score 2):

Wouldnt your case need a feature "other" of the list type (StringList for example) ? Because in this case the white dog is both happy and lazy, but since the feature is of the "Annotation" type (I assume) it'll contain only one value. At least that's how it works for plain UIMA annotators and pipelines.

Then you'ld check if the feature "other" contains "fat".

PS: I'm new to UIMA RUTA

Comment: Unfortunately, changing feature type to StringList did not work because of `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.StringList cannot be cast to org.apache.uima.cas.text.AnnotationFS` error, which I was not able to overcome

Comment: But this is because the feature will accept only a list of text , you should add the covered text to the feature `other` then use something like `INLIST` to check if the text is present there

That error was caused because you were trying to assign an `Annotation` value to a `StringList`

Comment: Hm, I understand the issue, but not sure how to fix it. Here is how I mark `Other` now: `PACKAGE dog; TYPESYSTEM dogTypeSystemDescriptor; WORDLIST OtherList = 'other.txt'; Document{-> MARKFAST(Other, OtherList)};`
Right now it creates an Annotation for each item from the `other.txt`. But how can I incorporate `StringList` type into that? Should I create `STRINGLIST` with the contents of the `other.txt` and pass it as an `other` feature to the `Dog`?

Comment: I tried something like this 

`STRINGLIST types;
STRING typeOther; dogType {-> MATCHEDTEXT(typeOther), ADD(types, typeOther)}; Document{-> CREATE(Dog, "other" = types)};` For some reason, using StringList isnt work (although the list is not empty, it doesnt create the feature, I dont know why), but if you change it to StringArray it'll work, but then I dont know if you'll be able to manipulate your data they way you need